# How to modify frame or padding of a polygon spplot in R?

Tags: r, frame, padding, lattice, polygons

I am plotting a choropleth map using `spplot`. My problem is that the plot frame is drawn by default tightly around the map (see the example code below). I would like to remove the frame entirely, but I can't use the option `trellis.par.set(axis.line=list(col=NA))`, as it will also leave out the axis lines of the legend. The legend lines are needed for clarity of reading the scale, and my color palette also includes white which needs to be framed.

As a quick fix, I tried adding a (white) polygon over the spplot frame, but it is drawn under the frame despite using option `under=F`:

```
#Plotting dummy polygons
library(sp)
p1 <- Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(13,15,20,20), c(8,13,14,8)))), "1")
p2 <- Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(20,20,28,30), c(8,15,12,7)))), "2")
p3 <- Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(15,20,25,22,18), c(8,8,7.5,0,2)))), "3")
polys <- SpatialPolygons(list(p1,p2,p3))
spdf <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(polys, data.frame(var1=c(1,4,8)))
spplot(spdf, col.regions=topo.colors(16))

#Adding an extra polygon to try to cover the frame
frame <- extent(spdf)
spplot(spdf, col.regions=topo.colors(16)) +
  layer(sp.polygons(as(frame,'SpatialPolygons'), lwd=3, col=3, fill=NA), under=F)
  #(using green here to actually see the box)
```

A second best solution would be to draw the frame further away from the map. Unfortunately I only found instructions on how to modify the outer margins, e.g.  `trellis.par.set(layout.heights=list(top.padding=3,bottom.padding=3))` , but I have no clue of how to control the *inner* margins (if there is such a thing in `spplot` plots).

Any help on modifying the frame or the inner margins in `spplot` would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**: Setting plot panel's outline transparent while keeping color key's outline black

```
spplot(spdf, col.regions=topo.colors(16), 
       par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent")),
       colorkey = list(axis.line = list(col = "black")))
```

[image: solution 1]

**Solution 2**: Padding the ranges of `xlim` & `ylim`

```
spplot(spdf, col.regions=topo.colors(16),
       xlim = c(spdf@bbox["x", "min"] - 3,
                spdf@bbox["x", "max"] + 3),
       ylim = c(spdf@bbox["y", "min"] - 3,
                spdf@bbox["y", "max"] + 3))
```

[image: solution 2]

Comment: Excellent, both solutions worked like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks very much, other list members from 2011 https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2011-July/012316.html couldn't figure this out and I wanted exactly this :)